# Firebase OIDC provider not working for firebase authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication

I use this document for firabse authentication with oidc in my angular website with oidc keycloak.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/openid-connectI got some errors. Also, I use some third party packages. it throw me some errors.
Please help me to find out the solutions.

angular-auth-oidc-client (npm: angular-auth-oidc-client )

angular-oauth2-oidc , angular-oauth2-oidc-jwks (npm: angular-oauth2-oidc )

oidc-client (npm: angular-oauth2-oidc )

Error:
`
INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE: The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired

INVALID_CREDENTIAL_OR_PROVIDER_ID

MISSING_OR_INVALID_NONCE : Nonce is missing in the request`